# Attoparsec compile errors

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I am trying to learn to use attoparsec. I am trying to parse a text file of the following format:

```
id int
call_uuid string 30
```

My code is here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Char (isDigit, isAlpha)
import Data.Attoparsec.Text (Parser, many1, letter, many', char, digit, string, 
                             (.*>), skipSpace, peekChar, decimal, 
                             isHorizontalSpace, skipWhile, parseOnly)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

schema :: Parser [(String, String, Maybe Int)]
schema = many1 typelines
  where
    colname = do
      c <- letter
      cs <- takeWhile (\x -> isDigit x || isAlpha x || x == '_')
      return (c:cs)

    int :: (Integral a, Read a) => Parser a
    int = read <$> decimal

    typelines = do
      cname <- colname
      skipWhile isHorizontalSpace
      tname <- takeWhile isAlpha
      skipWhile isHorizontalSpace
      c <- peekChar
      if c == '\n'
        then do { char '\n'; return (cname, tname, Nothing);}
        else do
          num <- int
          char '\n'
          return (cname, tname, num)

readDBTypes :: String -> IO [(String, String, Maybe Int)]
readDBTypes filename = do
  content <- T.readFile filename
  case (parseOnly schema content) of
    Left err -> do 
      print err
      return []
    Right v -> return v

main :: IO ()
main = do
  myLines <- readDBTypes "schema2.out"
  mapM_ print myLines
```

When I run, I get the following compiler errors (ghc 7.4)

```
$ runhaskell schema.hs

schema.hs:18:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `attoparsec-0.10.4.0:Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Parser
                                    Data.Text.Internal.Text t0'
                with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of `takeWhile'
    Probable cause: `takeWhile' is applied to too few arguments
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      cs <- takeWhile (\ x -> isDigit x || isAlpha x || x == '_')
    In the expression:
      do { c <- letter;
           cs <- takeWhile (\ x -> isDigit x || isAlpha x || x == '_');
           return (c : cs) }

schema.hs:22:20:
    Could not deduce (Integral String) arising from a use of `decimal'
    from the context (Integral a, Read a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 int :: (Integral a, Read a) => Parser a
      at schema.hs:22:5-26
    Possible fix:
      add (Integral String) to the context of
        the type signature for int :: (Integral a, Read a) => Parser a
      or add an instance declaration for (Integral String)
    In the second argument of `(<$>)', namely `decimal'
    In the expression: read <$> decimal
    In an equation for `int': int = read <$> decimal

schema.hs:27:16:
    Couldn't match expected type `attoparsec-0.10.4.0:Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Parser
                                    Data.Text.Internal.Text t0'
                with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
    In the return type of a call of `takeWhile'
    Probable cause: `takeWhile' is applied to too few arguments
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: tname <- takeWhile isAlpha
    In the expression:
      do { cname <- colname;
           skipWhile isHorizontalSpace;
           tname <- takeWhile isAlpha;
           skipWhile isHorizontalSpace;
           .... }
```

I am not sure if it is something to do with broken packages in my installation or if I not understanding something about the types. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

2 errors here, firstly `takeWhile` is defined as `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` by the prelude. you probably want `takeWhile` from `Data.Auttoparsec.Text` but you'll have to import that first and hide the prelude version.

```
import Prelude hiding (takeWhile)
import Data.Attoparsec.Text (takeWhile)
```

But if this code get's any bigger I'd advice

```
import qualified Data.AttoParsec.Text (takeWhile) as AP
```

And then just use `AP.takeWhile` since it's more readable when you don't have to run around looking to see what's hidden from Prelude.

Next `decimal` will return an `Integral a` all on it's own so don't fmap `read` on it. You don't actually need that `int` function. Haskell's typechecker is smart enough to unify `Integral a` with `Int` from your function so just use plain old `decimal`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `takeWhile` from `Data.Attoparsec.Text`, otherwise the compiler will use the one in `Prelude`.

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Text (takeWhile)
import Prelude hiding (takeWhile)
```

`decimal` already returns an `Integral a`; no need for `read`.

```
int :: Integral a => Parser a
int = decimal
```